# Removing duplicates of column2 then group them based on column1 , then sum the values of column3 in sql

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

The table looks like

```
column1  column2    column3
400196  2021-07-06   33
400196  2021-07-06   33
400196  2021-08-16   33
```

I want to get the sum of column3 values based on grouping of column 1 but the duplicate values of date should not be added

The desired output is:

```
column1  column3
400196   66
```

The query I wrote is

```
select sum(column3)
from table_name
group by column1
```

But this gives me result 99

Comment: If this is what your base tables look like, then you probably have an issue with your data model.  If the table is the results of a query, you should probably do the calculation at some other level (say before joining).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a two step process here, first remove duplicates, then aggregate and sum:

```sql
SELECT column1, SUM(column3) AS column3
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, column3 FROM yourTable) t
GROUP BY column1;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I need atleast 15 reputation to mark a correct answer , And I dont have them

Comment: No, you can click the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove duplicate values in a subquery:

```
select t.column1, sum(t.column3)
from (select distinct t.column1, t.column2, t.column3
      from t
     ) t
group by t.column1;
```

Note:  This sort of problem can arise when you are joining tables together.  Removing duplicates may not always be the right solution.  Often it is better to do the calculation before joining, so you don't have duplicate values to deal with.

Comment: @noob programmer: Please consider what Gordon is telling you (here and in the request comments). Such duplicates should not exist in the first place. If these are stored thus in a table, then you should reconsider your data model. If this is just a query result, you may want to rewrite that query.

Comment: I am working on a project and this data model is already created so, I cannot do anything to it